# ASP MVC Code First working with datetime computed columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-first, unit-of-work

I have gone through numerous examples, trying to figure out how to automatically set the `CreatedDate` value for each entity when saving changes to through `unitOfWork` and `Repository pattern`.

So what i have is simple `POCO`:

```
    public class Partners:IAutoGenerateDateFields
    {

        [Key]
        public int PartnerId { get; set; }
        public string PartnerCode { get; set; }
        public string PartnerName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public string TaxId { get; set; }
        public int PartnerTypeId { get; set; }
        public int PartnerStateId { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

      //  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
      //  public DateTime ModifiedDate { get;set;}
        public virtual Locations Location { get; set; }

    }
```

This Class implements the `IAutoGenerateDateFields` interface:

```
    interface IAutoGenerateDateFields
    {
        DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
      //  DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally in my `unitOfWork` class i check if the added/modified entity implements the above interface and set the `CreatedDate` value to current date:

```
    public void Save() {
        context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        var added = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                            .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Added)
                            .Select(t => t.Entity).ToArray();
        foreach (var entity in added) {
            if (entity is IAutoGenerateDateFields) {
                var track = entity as IAutoGenerateDateFields;
                track.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            }

        }

        var modified = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Modified)
                                .Select(t => t.Entity).ToArray();
        foreach (var entity in modified) {
            if (entity is IAutoGenerateDateFields) {
                var track = entity as IAutoGenerateDateFields;
                track.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But every time i hit `savechanges` i get an error that `CreatedDate` cannot be null. Thus, the entity does not get set with the current date.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` attribute, since you generate the value in your code.

I basically did the same thing yesterday, and the following code is working fine :

```
        var pendingChanges = GetContext().ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Select(e => e.Entity).ToList();

        foreach (var entity in pendingChanges)
        {
            entity.DateModified = DateTime.Now
        }
```